# MYSQL Specific Order With Conditionals

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, sql-order-by

Okay... I have three columns that I'd like to order based on their conditions.

- Column 1 (INT) = last_reboot
- Column 2 (BOOL) = onlinecheck
- Column 3 (INT) = drive_use

I'd like "last_reboot" to be default and ordered descending. If "onlinecheck" = 0, I'd like it to be at the top of my query else ordered by the the "last_reboot" desc. Lastly, if "drive_use" is > than 90 I'd like it ordered above "last_reboot" and below "onlinecheck" = 0 else ordered by "last_reboot".

EXAMPLE GOAL:

```
| last_reboot | onlinecheck | drive_use |
----------------------------------------------
|      15     |      0      |     80    |
|      90     |      1      |     91    |
|     320     |      1      |     80    |
|      45     |      1      |     50    | 
|      20     |      1      |     89    |
```

I was able to achieve half of this by using the ORDER BY FIELDS but once I introduce "drive_use" I cannot get it to function properly. "drive_use" is always ordered above "last_reboot" if it's NOT NULL.

```
SELECT * FROM <table> ORDER BY FIELD (onlinecheck, 0) DESC, (drive_per > 90), last_reboot DESC;
```

Any and all assistance greatly appreciated. Please let me know if further explanation is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to work with `ORDER BY CASE`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html

I'm not  sure I'm understanding the case well, but I think this comes quite close:

```
ORDER BY (CASE
    WHEN onlinecheck = 0 THEN 2 
    WHEN (drive_use > 90) THEN 1 
    ELSE 0
END) DESC,
last_reboot DESC
```

[Here a DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tuN2w4yTExymCowa7NYcq6/0)

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
order by 
    onlinecheck,
    drive_use > 90 desc,
    last_reboot desc
```

This puts rows with `onlinecheck = 0` first. Then, rows with `drive_use` above `90`. Ties are broken with a descending sort on `last_reboot`.

Comment: drive_per and last_reboot are in proper order but onlinecheck regardless of bool is at the bottom of the query.

Comment: @pastyj: this puts rows that have `onlinecheck = 0` first. [Here is a db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0a411b764bab164f590255ab531d8572) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help with this. The only problem with this solution, was if "drive_use" had a NULL value. If "drive_use" = NULL it would query below "last_reboot".